# Can't unlock APFS external drive

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, disk-utility

I've recently come across an issue with my external HDD (2TB, LaCiE) drive which is formatted with APFS. I have three volumes under a 2TB container which are all APFS (Case-sensitive, Encrypted).

1. When plugging in the drive, I see the following error for each of my volumes:
   [image: The disk "Old Backups" can't be unlocked. A problem was detected with the disk that prevents it from being unlocked.]
2. When trying to recover with Disk Drill, which has worked in the past, I only see "Updating disk list..."
   [image: Updating disk list...]
3. When usig [libfsapfs](https://github.com/libyal/libfsapfs)'s `fsapfsinfo`, tool, I see the following error:

```
fsapfsinfo 20210424

Apple File System (APFS) information:

File system hierarchy:
Unable to print file system hierarchy.
libfsapfs_internal_volume_unlock: invalid volume - missing key bag.
libfsapfs_volume_unlock: unable to unlock volume.
info_handle_get_volume_by_index: unable to unlock volume.
info_handle_file_system_hierarchy_fprint: unable to retrieve volume: 0.
```

Any and all help would be appreciated! Thanks :~)

Comment: 1) Please add the output of `diskutil list` and `diskutil apfs list` to the question (at least anything related to the drive, partitions, containers and volumes. 2) Have you used Disk Utility's First Aid? 3) Have you tried `'diskutil apfs unlockVolume`? 4) Have your searched the web with your error message?